# How to correctly pass array of structs from MQL4 to C# DLL library

Tags: c#, dll, unmanaged, mql4

I am writing a script in **`MQL4`** language for MetaTrader Terminal 4 which is using **C# DLL library** for further data processing.

What I'm trying to do is to pass an array of following `MQL4`-structures:

```
struct marketUpdate
{    
    double openPrice;
    double closePrice;
    double highPrice;
    double lowPrice;
    int volume;
    double pipValuePerLot;
    int intervalLength;
    string symbol;
    string time;
};
```

to this function in `C# DLL`:

```
[DllExport("HistoricMarketData", CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static int HistoricMarketData(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, SizeParamIndex = 1)] MarketUpdate[] unmanagedArray,
    int length)
{
    // further processing
}
```

This is the function definition on `MQL4` side:

```
int HistoricMarketData(
          marketUpdate &marketUpdates[],
          int length);
```

and this is the structure on `C#` side:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct MarketUpdate
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    public double openPrice;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    [FieldOffset(8)]
    public double closePrice;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    [FieldOffset(16)]
    public double highPrice;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    [FieldOffset(24)]
    public double lowPrice;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [FieldOffset(32)]
    public int volume;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.R8)]
    [FieldOffset(36)]
    public double pipValuePerLot;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [FieldOffset(44)]
    public int intervalLength;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    [FieldOffset(48)]
    public string symbol;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)]
    [FieldOffset(60)]
    public string time;
}
```

My problem is that it is not working when calling `HistoricMarketData` from `MQL4`. The script either crashes whole MetaTrader program or throws an exception and fails.

As you can see I'm using Robert Giesecke's **Unmanaged Exports** library to make it works and I correctly imported `DLL` to `MQL4` as other functions inside are working without any issue.

After lot of trial and error I was able to find out that when I remove those 2 string attributes (`symbol` and `time`) from structure all works as expected and structure is correctly passed to `C#` function.

**So my question is how to correctly pass string in structure from `MQL4` to `C#`?**

I already tried to change `UnmanagedType` parameter at `MarshalAs` annotation in structure to other string variants but it didn't help. It also didn't help to change `string` to `char[]` on both sides.

I'll appreciate any advices or help.

Thanks!

Comment: Ahoj, ide o pokročilejšie spracovanie orderov a market dát pomocou stratégií na `C#` strane.

Comment: Ok, asi mi radeji napis na email, tohle asi neni hobby-projekt :o)

Comment: Nemôžem sa k nemu dopátrať :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Welcome to the Wild Worlds of `MQL4`
 where `string` is not string,
but a `struct`

So,
this,
and not only this,
was causing a lot of headache for re-integrationg `MQL4` with `DLL`-s

**My own strategy is:**
1) avoid `MQL4`-strings, if not of a core importance,
2) if needed, pass them via a `DLL`-proxy utility function, which handles needed conversions:

```
#import <dll>                                        // DLL-native CallSignatures: 
...
int          mql4s_send ( int socket, uchar &text[] );
...
#import
                                                     // DLL-proxy with  StringToCharArray() conversion:
int              s_send ( int socket, string text ) { uchar textChar[]; StringToCharArray( text, textChar );
    return ( mql4s_send (     socket,                       textChar ) );
  }
```

Anyway,
rather do read `MQL4` Help, actually **better re-read** it again after each MetaTrader Build update ( yes, I am saying, that new help files contain ( at least ) some remarks on new `MQL4`-features, that have no other easy way to find and learn about -- it saves a lot of time. With code-base under maintenance, spanning more than a few hundreds man*years, I know the pain very well ).

> The following can't be used for parameters in imported functions:
>   ·pointers;
>   ·links to objects that contain dynamic arrays and/or pointers.
>   
>   Classes, string arrays or **complex** objects that contain strings and/or dynamic arrays of any types **cannot be passed** as a parameter to functions imported from DLL.

But Devil is hidden in details like this ( indirectly forbidden feature ):

> ...
>   **Simple Structures**
>   
>   Structures that do **not** contain strings or objects of dynamic arrays are called simple structures; variables of such structures can be freely copied to each other, even if they are different structures. Variables of simple structures, as well as their array **can be passed** as parameters to functions imported from DLL.

Comment: Ahh, thanks for clarification. I have read the documentation but I must have missed that part with simple structures and pointers. Could you please elaborate more how to use that proxy function? Should I pass string separately outside the structure (because passing strings as function arguments works well)? Thanks.

Comment: Yessssss, the point is rather hidden in plain text reading, I used to headbang into this during previous Build updates, once stable DLL-interfaces have after many years working fine suddenly stopped working/crashed. **A good lesson from *New*-`MQL4.56789` creeping.**